# Deleted linux partition from Windows and can't boot into windows now

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I have tried to install linux on my Winodws 10 machine and the installation had some issues. I removed it from Windows before changing the bootmanager from grub. Now when I restarted, I get the following:

```
                      GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubujntu3.2
Minimal BASH-LIKE line editing is supported. For the first word, TAb lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

I have access to the linux USB which I used to install ubuntu.

I am unable to get the bootscreen so that i can reinstall ubuntu and will be able to see the option to boot into windows again.

Comment: You need to boot from Windows installation disk and restore bootloader.

Comment: There are two ways. One if you have Ubuntu live usb/cd, then you can install Ubuntu and dual boot along with windows. Another is that if you have a Windows usb/DVD, then you can replace grub by windows bootloader and have only Windows installed. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @CedaEI  I have ubuntu usb. I am not sure how to boot using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Ubuntu press the key to enter BIOS options. The key is usually `ESC`, `F1-12` or `Delete`. If you are unsure which key does it, try pressing each key one during each boot. After that, change the boot order and bring USB to top. 
Now, install Ubuntu as per the screen instructions. This must also restore grub and allow you to choose to boot into either Ubuntu or Windows.

- If you can boot into Ubuntu but cannot boot into Windows, then after booting into  Ubuntu open a terminal by pressing `CTRL+ ALT + T` and type in `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` Next, after this command is completely executed, run `sudo update-grub`.
- If you can't boot into either OSes after installing Ubuntu, then boot into live USB and choose try Ubuntu and repeat the above process.